# How to use checkbox to get value in true or false?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, oop

I have a variable called String CustomerId in my main window.

```
String CustomerId = customer_id_textbox.Text
```

Similarly, I have a variable called bool customer_is_adult in my main window.

I'm trying to find out how can I use checkbox to assign value to customer_is_adult. 
If customer_checkbox is checked the value of this variable should be true, if it's unchecked, it's value should be false.

Comment: What have you already tried? any code snippet?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Note that the [tag:visual-studio] description says *"Use this tag if you have a specific question about Visual Studio features and functionality. DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio."*. You can [edit] your question to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Checked` property on the Checkbox object, which you can use here.

```
bool customer_is_adult = customer_checkbox.Checked;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CheckBox` `CheckedChanged` event :

```
private void customer_checkbox_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    customer_is_adult = customer_checkbox.Checked;
}
```

Please take a look at [CheckBox.CheckedChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void CustomerCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bool customer_is_adult = true;
        }
        private void CustomerCheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bool customer_is_adult = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please Try this Code



<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <CheckBox
            Content="CheckBox"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="10,10,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Checked="CheckBox_Checked"
            Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>




public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Handle(sender as CheckBox);
        }

        private void CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Handle(sender as CheckBox);
        }

        void Handle(CheckBox checkBox)
        {
            // Use IsChecked.
            bool flag = checkBox.IsChecked.Value;

            // Assign Window Title.
            this.Title = "IsChecked = " + flag.ToString();
        }
    }
```